# Remove noise from VGA image

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, computer-vision, object-recognition, deep-learning

I have 2 color images generated from same X-ray machines, but one of the image is obtained using VGA cable. Therefore the RGB intensities differ in the 2 images. I am using Object detection to detect threat objects in the x-ray images. Is there any way i can remove the noise added due to VGA so that the images have similar RGB intensities?

Comment: Just two very brief questions: 1) By "noise" do you mean a slight coloration of the images or something else? and 2) What is a "threat object"?

Comment: 1) Yes by noise i mean slight coloration,  eg. white pixels become grayish.(In images obtained directly from x-ray scanner the background pixels are white whereas in images from VGA cable the background pixels are gray.)2) Threat objects means guns,knives etc which are not allowed in airport luggages.